# Can I cast Elemental Body while Wild-Shaped?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, druid, wild-shape, polymorph

I have a level 13 Druid with access to the Cloud (Air Domain). My level 7 domain spell is Elemental Body IV (Air). Can I cast that while I am in a Wild Shape? Or does polymorph rules prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can only have one of those effects active at a time.

Relevant rules:

[Wild Shape](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-) "functions like "the beast shape I spell, except as noted here."

[Beast Shape](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape/) and [Elemental Body](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/elemental-body/) are  transmutation (polymorph) so polymorph rules apply. And, of course, the rule on [polymorph](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph) you were concerned about (which also references Wild Shape):

> You can only be affected by one polymorph spell at a time. If a new polymorph spell is cast on you (or you activate a polymorph effect, such as wild shape), you can decide whether or not to allow it to affect you, taking the place of the old spell. In addition, other spells that change your size have no effect on you while you are under the effects of a polymorph spell.

Because of this, whichever effect, Wild Shape or spell, is activated second takes precedence (although you can decide to ignore it). Ask your GM about how they interpret "taking the place of the old spell".

Comment: At the end of the spell, would I return to wild-shape or my original form?

Comment: That would be another question that should be made, but I believe your original form, based on the language "taking the place of the old spell"

Comment: You may want to clarify that they can cast *Elemental Body* while wild shaped (assuming they have the [proper feats](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/natural-spell-final/)) and it replaces the current polymorph.

Comment: I think the rule is pretty clear but I'll write up a paraphrased summary in not-legalspeak.